# Phaser Uncaught ReferenceError: game is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, phaser-framework

I'm creating my first game with Phaser and am using requirejs.

I wrote this code:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'game',
  paths: {
    Phaser: 'js/phaser.min',
    BootState: 'states/boot',
    MenuState: 'states/menu',
    PreloadState: 'states/preload',
  }
});

var BootState = require(['Phaser']);
var MenuState = require(['MenuState']);
var PreloadState = require(['PreloadState']);

new Phaser.Game(1334, 750, Phaser.AUTO, 'bird-reborn');

// Game States

game.state.add('boot', BootState);
game.state.add('menu', MenuState);
game.state.add('play', PlayState);
game.state.add('preload', PreloadState);

game.state.start('boot');
```

And have this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: game is not defined`

How do I fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
new Phaser.Game(1334, 750, Phaser.AUTO, 'bird-reborn');
```

By this :

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1334, 750, Phaser.AUTO, 'bird-reborn');
```